# Implementing Unique LP Token Features: Rewarding Liquidity Providers with Free LP Tokens

Tags: contract-development

I'm working on a coin and aiming to introduce a unique feature where liquidity providers can mint additional LP tokens as a reward for providing liquidity to the pool, excluding gas fees.

However, when attempting to use the `mint()` function through BscScan, I encounter strange errors and very high gas fees. If anyone has insights into potential solutions or suggestions, please provide a reply. Additional information can be provided upon request. Thank you in advance, and have a great day!